# Do you know a good freeware that creates C++ or C# classes (data model) from XSD?

Tags: c#, c++, xml, xsd

I know examples but there are not free tools. Need one that is free and reliable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what type of "free" you are looking for but I have used the open source codesynthesis xsd tool www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/ for c++ data binding.

Comment: btw it costs money for commercial use.

Answer (score 8):

You can use XSD.exe, which is part of the Microsoft .Net SDK.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fe6f2099-b7b4-4f47-a244-c96d69c35dec&displaylang=en

A sample usage of this tool would be (from the command line):

```
xsd.exe MySchema.xsd /classes /namespace:My.Schema.Namespace
```

which would output a class file `MySchema.cs` which contained the generated code for your schema.  It can also output a VB or CPP file if you specify the language flag.

Comment: Just what I was about to say ;-p

Comment: I am not familiar with .NET platform at all, could you say how I should use XSD.exe if I have installed the platform? Thanks.

Comment: Google for XSD.exe. More than enough information on MSDN and lots of other sites...

Comment: Narek I was just editing my answer to provide an example.  See if that helps.

Comment: For more info on using the XSD tool check out this MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx

Comment: AFAICT Microsoft's XSD cannot generate C++, just .net languages.